# Detecting all the selected IIS Authentication modes

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis

For some particular reason, I need to detect all the selected/enabled authentication modes of a web app running on IIS (7). Checking the `IPersonal` object or the `System.Web.Configuration.AuthenticationMode`  enumeration does not help for the following reason: they show only if no authentication, forms authentication or windows authentication is being used. The same goes for `Web.config`.

What I really need to get is "list of all enabled authentication modes". If, for example, both `Anonymous Authentication` and `Forms Authentication` are enabled, I need to somehow find that out.

I've also tried to read these settings using the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` namespace, but I can't seam to find anything useful.

Is there a way to programmatically get the authentication modes for a particular web app?

Answer (score 1):

You may use following code for same:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

private void CheckAuthenticationModes()
{
  using(ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager()) { 
     Configuration config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
     //replace myWebApp with your webapplication name.   
     ConfigurationSection anonymousAuthenticationSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication", "myWebApp");
     var anonymousAuthentication= anonymousAuthenticationSection["enabled"];

     ConfigurationSection windowsAuthenticationSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication", "myWebApp");
     var windowsAuthentication= windowsAuthenticationSection["enabled"];

  }
}
```